# 'arange' of float gives wrong border

Tags: python, numpy

Using NumPy 1.24.3 with Python 3 I get unexpected output from `np.arange`:

```py
import numpy as np

np.arange(0.01,0.08,0.01)
# Out[30]: array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08])

np.arange(0.07,0.00,-0.01)
# Out[48]: array([0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.  ])
```

Expected results:

```py
import numpy as np

np.arange(0.01,0.08,0.01)
# Out[30]: array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07])

np.arange(0.07,0.00,-0.01)
# Out[48]: array([0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01])
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrange the list of list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869059/arrange-the-list-of-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in numpy documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.24/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). The length of the output might not be numerically stable. You should use [numpy.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/1.24/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace).